# Why do I get this bash error? "export: `/home/atul/Public/Android': not a valid identifier."

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I did this from the ~ directory.

I typed this command
`sudo gedit .bashrc`

then I appended these lines to the file and saved it.

```
#Adding flutter and android path
export ANDROID= "$HOME/Public/Android"
export FLUTTER= "$ANDROID/flutter"
export PATH= "$PATH:$FLUTTER/bin"
```

Now when I open the terminal I get the following error:

```
bash: export: `/home/atul/Public/Android': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/flutter': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/atul/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/bin': not a valid identifier
atul@mintMate:~$
```

Its good that I have fish installed else I wouldn't have been able to
use the terminal.
Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a space after the `=` in your assignments.  Change them to this.

```
export ANDROID="$HOME/Public/Android"
export FLUTTER="$ANDROID/flutter"
export PATH="$PATH:$FLUTTER/bin"
```